# FFmpeg TCP point to point streaming with tee muxer - handle network disconnections

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, tcp, keepalive

we are using FFmpeg for live streaming between two computers (point to point streaming) using TCP.
The streaming works fine and we wanted to add support for two features:

1. Save the stream locally in addition to streaming it to the remote pc
2. Handle network interruptions

For the first item we started using the Tee Muxer and it solves the first problem.
However, we didn't manage keep the connection alive during network interruptions , the stream doesn't recover if the network if disconnected more than ~10 seconds.

A little more technical information:
The streaming ffmpeg command:

> ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30.0 -pixel_format uyvy422 -i "0:0" -preset veryfast -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -sc_threshold 0 -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -af "aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0" -r 30.0 -f tee -map 0 "[onfail=ignore]test_new.ts|[f=fifo:fifo_format=mpegts:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1:recover_any_error=1]tcp://[host]:[port]?timeout=900000000"

The receiving end:

> ffmpeg -i tcp://host:port?listen&timeout=900000000&listen_timeout=300000 ...

After a few seconds , we get at the streaming end the following error:

> Connection to tcp://[host]:[port]?timeout=900000000 failed: Network is unreachable

And the stream never recovers

We want to keep the tcp connection alive as long as possible (we choose 5 minutes for testing)

Does anyone know if this can be done and how?

Thank you

Comment: Does a netcat session between the same endpoints remain persistent?

Comment: not sure what you mean , could you elaborate a little more?